# Number of solutions for $x$ of such form that $\frac{(x-1)^y}{x} = z,\;y>2,\;z \neq 0$

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

Consider

$$\frac{(x-1)^y}{x} = z,\;y>2,\;z \neq 0$$

where $y$ is an integer.

In relation to solutions for $x$; How could one prove that:

$(1)$: There are $y$ solutions for $x$, in total.

$(2)$: If $y$ is odd, and $z$ is positive, there is $1$ real solution, and $y-1$ complex solutions.

$(3)$: If $y$ is even, and $z$ is positive, there are $2$ real solutions, and $y-2$ complex solutions.

$(4)$: If $y$ is odd, and $z$ is negative, there is $1$ real solution, and $y-1$ complex solutions.

$(5)$: If $y$ is even, and $z$ is negative, there are no real solutions, and $y$ complex solutions.

Comment: Do you want $y$ to be a positive / non-negative integer? Otherwise, what does it mean to have $-1$ solutions? If so, the condition of $y<2$ is very very restrictive. I can think of only 2 numbers, 1 which is odd and 1 which is even.

Comment: If $y=2$ is allowed (see previous comment), then (5) is false since $x=-2$ is a solution with $z= -\frac{9}{2}$

Comment: A fatal typo has been corrected; $<$ was supposed to be $>$...
My shift key seem to be conspiring against me...